# Pandas: find the n lowest values each m rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a Counter, increasing by 1 each 24 rows, and a value column, like below.

```
    value   counter
0   0.00    1
1   0.00    1
2   0.00    1
3   0.00    1
4   0.00    1
5   0.00    1
6   0.00    1
7   0.00    1
8   55.00   1
9   90.00   1
10  49.27   1
11  51.80   1
12  49.06   1
13  43.46   1
14  45.96   1
15  43.95   1
16  45.00   1
17  43.97   1
18  42.00   1
19  41.14   1
20  43.92   1
21  51.74   1
22  40.85   1
23  0.00    2
24  0.00    2
25  0.00    2
26  0.00    2
27  0.00    2
28  0.00    2
29  0.00    2
...     ...     ...
187     82.38   9
188     66.89   9
189     59.83   9
190     52.46   9
191     40.48   9
192     28.87   9
193     41.90   9
194     42.56   9
195     40.93   9
196     40.02   9
197     36.54   9
198     33.70   9
199     38.99   9
200     46.10   9
201     44.82   9
202     0.00    9
203     0.00    9
204     0.00    9
205     0.00    9
206     0.00    9
207     0.00    10
208     0.00    10
209     0.00    10
210     74.69   10
211     89.20   10
212     74.59   10
213     55.11   10
214     58.39   10
215     40.81   10
216     45.06   10
```

I would like to know if there is a way to create a third column with the 4 lowest values in each Group where the Counter has the same value. See below an example for the first Group with Count=1:

```
 value counter value 2
0   0.00    1   0.00
1   0.00    1   0.00
2   0.00    1   0.00
3   0.00    1   0.00
4   0.00    1   0.00
5   0.00    1   0.00
6   0.00    1   0.00
7   0.00    1   0.00
8   55.00   1   0.00
9   90.00   1   0.00
10  49.27   1   0.00
11  51.80   1   0.00
12  49.06   1   0.00
13  43.46   1   43.46
14  45.96   1   0.00
15  43.95   1   0.00
16  45.00   1   0.00
17  43.97   1   0.00
18  42.00   1   42.00
19  41.14   1   41.14
20  43.92   1   0.00
21  51.74   1   0.00
22  40.85   1   40.85
```

I know about some functions like `nsmallest(n,'column')` but I don't know how to limit it with the Count grouping

Any idea? thank you in advance! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first filter out rows with `0` values in `value`, sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and get [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) for top `4` values, last add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filling `0` for not matched values:

```
df['value 2'] = (df[df['value'] != 0]
                   .sort_values('value')
                   .groupby('counter')['value'].head(4)
                   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0))

print (df)
    value  counter  value 2
0    0.00        1     0.00
1    0.00        1     0.00
2    0.00        1     0.00
3    0.00        1     0.00
4    0.00        1     0.00
5    0.00        1     0.00
6    0.00        1     0.00
7    0.00        1     0.00
8   55.00        1     0.00
9   90.00        1     0.00
10  49.27        1     0.00
11  51.80        1     0.00
12  49.06        1     0.00
13  43.46        1    43.46
14  45.96        1     0.00
15  43.95        1     0.00
16  45.00        1     0.00
17  43.97        1     0.00
18  42.00        1    42.00
19  41.14        1    41.14
20  43.92        1     0.00
21  51.74        1     0.00
22  40.85        1    40.85
23   0.00        2     0.00
24   0.00        2     0.00
25   0.00        2     0.00
26   0.00        2     0.00
27   0.00        2     0.00
```